# Only once per day validation for user from a list view in Android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, countdowntimer

I need to validate the user to pick only one item per day using timer or alarm manager in Android. Is there a better way to design it, so that it is easy check if the user does not get more than one item per day. I have a list of ten items displayed in a list view. The user get an item from the list. He should get only one item. If he tries again, he should be alerted that one item only once per day.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Effects.getInstance().init(this);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    List<ItemDetail> itemList = createItems(10);

    // Load animation
    final Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_anim);

    final ArrayAdapter<ItemDetail> aAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<ItemDetail>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            itemList);
    lv.setAdapter(aAdpt);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, final int position, long id) {
            MediaPlayer  mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.gum_bubble_pop);
            mPlayer.start();
            anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long lastCheckedMillis = 0;
                    long diffMillis = now - lastCheckedMillis;
                    if( diffMillis >= (3600000  * 24) ) {
                      // store now (i.e. in shared prefs)

                      // do the check
                    } else {
                       // too early
                    }



                    if(aAdpt.getCount()==9) { 
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You can get only one gift per day "+now, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                    ItemDetail item = aAdpt.getItem(position);
                    aAdpt.remove(item);
                    }
                }
            });
            view.startAnimation(anim);

        }
    });

}

private List<ItemDetail> createItems(int size) {
    List<ItemDetail> result = new ArrayList<ItemDetail>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        ItemDetail item = new ItemDetail(i, "Gift " + (i + 1));
        result.add(item);
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

did you try this

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

if(hours*3600 + minutes*60 + seconds < 1800){
    // Day changed since last task
}
```

As your trigger loop every 30 minutes, this code will check if the time is between midnight and midnight and a half. So put this code in your trigger, and inside the if, write the code you want to be executed if day changed since last time the loop ran.